# Getting error when running test project using cmd file

Tags: .net, powershell, batch-file, dotnet-test

I have a test project and I was running the test project by setting some variable using cmd file.
This is the file content.

```
#launchtests.cmd
SETLOCAL
SET MyTestProperty='ValueFromCommand'
DOTNET TEST MyTestProject.csproj
```

I kept this in the same folder of project file location. But when I try executing this via Powershell, Getting below error.

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-TEST does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

[image]

Did I missed to install anything here?

Comment: If you are just trying to run tests from the dotnet CLI and you have the SDK installed, `dotnet test <path to test project>` will suffice. No need for any capital letters or hyphens.

Comment: @Ash Thanks. It worked. Never thought Caps will cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ash in comment, Caps was issue. When I applied
`dotnet test MyTestProject.csproj` It worked.